# AR.js does not show video when I hold the camera up to the marker

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe

**Assumption.**
I want to use AR.js technology to display an video when I hold the camera up to a marker.
No matter how many times I hold it up, the video does not appear.

**What we want to achieve**
We would like to play the video with sound when the camera is held over the marker. (I want to play the video with sound on iPhone as well.)

**Problem/error message being encountered**
No video is played back when the camera is held over the marker.
I have checked for file name or code errors or something like that, but it doesn't seem to be there.

I just tried accessing the actual site and the camera no longer shows up either. I've put the situation on video.
[enter link description here](https://twitter.com/hilOiZOjS1ejq0G/status/1515238320435261440)

**Source code in question**

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
<!-- A-Frame Loading Libraries -->
<script src="aframe-master.min.js"></script>
<!-- AR.js Loading Libraries -->
<script src="aframe-ar.js"></script>
</head>
<body style='margin:0px; overflow:hidden;'>
        <a-assets>
           <video id="ar-video" poster="img.jpg" crossOrigin="anonymous" type="video/mp4" src="tanaka.mp4" muted="true" autoplay loop="true" playsinline webkit-playsinline controls />
          </a-assets>
          <!-- Hide screen display for debugging and buttons for VR, respectively. -->
        <a-scene embedded arjs="debugUIEnabled:false;" vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
          <!-- Load the ".patt" file created this time -->
          <a-marker type='pattern' url='pattern-movie-tanaka.patt'>
              <a-video src="#ar-video" width="2.6" height="1.4" position="0 0 0" rotation="270 0 0" play="true"></a-video>
          </a-marker>
<a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
        
        <script>
          window.addEventListener('click', function () {
          var v = document.querySelector('#ar-video');
          v.play();
          });
        </script>
        <script>
          // Added variable definitions for video storage
          var video = null;
  
          AFRAME.registerComponent('registerevents', {
              init: function () {
                  var marker = this.el;
  
                  // Registration of events where markers are detected
                  marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function () {
  
                      // After marker recognition, video playback
                      if (video == null) {
                          video = document.querySelector('#ar-video');
                      }
                      video.play();
                  });
  
                  // Registration of events with missing markers
                  marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function () {
                      
                      // If marker recognition fails, video stops
                      video.pause();
                  });
              }
          });
  
          
          window.addEventListener('click', function () {
              video = document.querySelector('#ar-video');
              video.play();
          });
      </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you make your script do *anything* if the camera is held up to the marker? Playing a video seems incidental here.

Comment: Are you asking me to take a picture of what happens when I hold up the camera?I will publish it when I take it.

Comment: No, not at all. I'm saying you need to narrow down the issue, and do something else instead of playing a video (like a console.log() for instance would be the obvious choice). What I'm saying is that it's not clear whether a) detecting the marker or b) playing the video is what fails (or both), and we need to find out which it is first.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know since I am a beginner, but I see that it is necessary to log it. I will try.

Comment: Yes, just log something inside the `markerFound` handler function.

Comment: After re-installing the library, the camera is now visible. Markers are still unreadable, so I'm going to log them. i'll try logging them in xcode.

Comment: Was I able to see the marker log in Xcode?

Comment: Good question. Were you?

Comment: Logging is one thing, but really you need to debug a simplified setup: 1) default hiro marker with a box, if working -> 2) `pattern-movie-tanaka.patt` pattern marker with a box -> 3) video + play/stop with vanilla `a-frame` (without `ar.js`) -> 4) your current setup

Comment: I used the following site and it displayed well.
https://ar-js-org.github.io/studio/